# Isekai Slice of life village management manga

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I think it is about a person who gets the village as inheritance and to make his village progress he starts to ask people to come to his village and reside in it for a stipend. Obviously at first everybody thought it was a scam but a high ranking female mercenary, saint and many other hotshots arrive.

The main character (mayor of the village) doesn't have any special skill I think but good social skills as he befriends a demon lord at one point

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Are there any SF or fantasy elements to this story?  Magical characters, that kind of thing?

Comment: Yes, I mean it is isekai so there are characters like demon lord and holy saint. In more detail if I can say is about these characters as i far as I can remember is that demon lord i hard-working person because of that his subordinates give all the work to him coz of that he leaves his place and comes to the MC village and kinda becomes their friend. And I think with saint is that she got nervous I think I don't know the background about her actually, but she is kinda in trouble where she used to work.

Comment: See, these are good details to add to the question. :)  A demon lord who wants to get away from his job is something that would greatly restrict the number of possibilities.

Answer (score 5):

This is *[Tensei Ryoushu no Yuuryou Kaitaku: Zense no Kioku wo Ikashite White ni Tsutometara, Yuunou na Jinzai ga Atsumari Sugimashita](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=191926)*.

> I was working for a black company<sup>*</sup> when I collapsed from exhaustion and woke up to find that I had been reincarnated as the son of a weak lord in another world. I was attacked by a demon, lost my parents, and took over a territory that no longer had any residents... The path I chose to survive was to gather people under extremely white conditions!
> This is a territory management fantasy that starts with no residents!

After his parents die from a monster attack, Lyle Alenz tries to strengthen his inherited territory by recruiting people. He used to work for a terrible exploitative company in his previous life, and tried to use extremely favorable conditions, but the other residents of the world are used to being exploited and didn't believe it.

[image: Flyer]

One person does accept it; an S-ranked female knight

[image: Knight]

The cover of the first volume shows the knight and who I assume are the demon lord and saint(ess) from the question.

[image: Cover]

*: The term [Black Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_company_(Japanese_term)) refers to exploitative work places in Japan.

Comment: Yes, this is the one. thankss

Comment: @user153026 - Don't forget to mark this as 'accepted' by clicking the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Is it *[Shokubutsu Mahou Cheat de Nonbiri Ryoushu Seikatsu Hajimemasu](https://myanimelist.net/manga/139593/Shokubutsu_Mahou_Cheat_de_Nonbiri_Ryoushu_Seikatsu_Hajimemasu__Zense_no_Chishiki_wo_Kushi_shite_Nougyou_shitara_Gyakuten_Jinsei_Hajimatta_Ken/news)*
(*Use Cheat Plant Magic and Live Comfortably as a Lord!*)?

> Elt, who reincarnated in an MMORPG as an aristocrat, was branded as incompetent and was thrown out as a manager of a remote area with zero territories. However, his "plant magic" was the best all-purpose magic for territorial development! As he cultivated by utilizing the magic that produces from crops to buildings and the knowledge of the previous life, the territory increased and became lively.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think this is the one, as I have read this one. And the one I am looking for in that the MC (mayor of the village) doesn't have any special skill I think but good social skills as he befriends a demon lord at one point